# python zip extraction in background

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, background-process

I am uploading large zip files in to the system. where zip extraction may take several minutes. I want to send this zip extraction in to the background as don't want to block the UI.

```
_.unzip(filePath ,uploadPath) #is it possible to make it async or independent?
```

Comment: As you tagged, why don't you use `subprocess` or `multiprocessing` or pass the task to other workers.

Comment: can I pass internal functions as well ? I mean it is not an external shell command

Comment: If you are using `multiprocessing`, you can use `proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=unzip, args=(filePath, uploadPath)); proc.start()` and `proc.join()` later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) module!

```
import threading

def do_unzipping():
    _.unzip(filePath ,uploadPath)

    update_ui("Unzipping Finished!")

threading.Thread(target = do_unzipping).start()
continue_with_unblocked_ui()
```

[Nice threading tutorial](http://pymotw.com/2/threading/).

Comment: Probably _not_ a good idea to update the ui from the separate thread. `tkinter` for example doesn't support it.